# How to append the date to log file before it's name?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, logrotate

I want to append the date to my log file before its name.

`/opt/logs/myapp.log`

```
{

        rotate 6
        hourly
        dateext
        dateformat %Y-%m-%d
        ifempty
        postrotate
                service rsyslog rotate >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

This is my configuration.
With this configuration, it is rotating the logfile but it is appending the date at the end of the  name

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
rotate 6
hourly
dateext
ifempty
postrotate
      day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
      mv myapp.log /var/log/{$day}myapp.log.1
      service rsyslog rotate >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
endscript
```

Comment: needs `${day}myapp.log`.  and quotes.

Comment: Hey rahul , thanks for answer. But, in the following line theres is some problem mv myapp.log /var/log/$daymyapp.log

Comment: It is throwing no myapp.log file kind of error I think it because after rotating the file the rotated files name will be some extension like myapp.log.1 .